# Jira issue collector popup window injection with jQuery

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jira

Have a question regarding Jira's issue collector.

*For those who has Jira, but does not have an idea about issue collector - Administrator -> Projects -> AnyProject -> Issue Collector (Left) -> Add Issue Collector*. After all configurations, you will get a js script, which has to be embedded into an html page. This js script has the ability to trigger Jira issue collector popup window.

I want to display popup issue collector window and inject it with some additional html tags.
Basically i would like to split popup window in two and display "register new issue" on the top part of the window and all registered issues on the bottom of the window.

For now i display popup when page is loaded (this script triggers issue collector's popup window when web page is loaded - jQuery(document).ready(..) ):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="put_your_own_jira_issue_collector_link"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.ajax({
    url: "put_your_own_jira_issue_collector_link",
    type: "get",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script"
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window.ATL_JQ_PAGE_PROPS = {
        "triggerFunction": function (showCollectorDialog) {
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                showCollectorDialog();

            });
        }
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The popup window is displayed when we open a web page. The structure of the page is:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div id="atlwdg-blanket" class="atlwdg-blanket">
   <div id="atlwdg-container" class="atlwdg-popup atlwdg-box-shadow atlwdg-hidden">
    <iframe id="atlwdg-frame">
     <html class="chrome webkit">
      <body id="atlScriptlet">
       <div class="aui-dialog collector-dialog custom-collector">
        <form id="jic-collector-form" class="aui ">
         ...
```

then i tried injecting using jQuery, but without any luck. I couldn't inject directly into the popup. So i started wondering if it is possible to inject when it is cross-domain request or not. Or maybe there exist another way to do this task

Can someone experienced with jQuery please help

P.S. one more detail - this page will be displayed in a WebView component in another environment other than any commercial browser

Graphically:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to publish a http://sscce.org/ ? I already have a JIRA instance available... just explain how to configure your code with it.

Comment: @YvesMartin I can only publish _sce_. You might want to generate your own issue collector using Jira environment

Comment: @YvesMartin edited original question with some more possibly useful information

Answer (score 2):

I must admit I'm not up to speed with jira but it looks to me like you're trying to write inside the iframe from the parent window.

Browsers like chrome don't allow that, even from the same origin.

Have you tried writing anything else in the popup?

Comment: Tried appending divs and changing inner/outer HTML, but with no affect. Same appenditures work for the container of iframe though

Comment: This question is not about jira, it is more about the use of jQuery and about what is possible and what is not. I have read that some browsers do not allow such kind of injections and that there is a general problem with injections in iframe. But I thought that there might be a woraround especially in my case - when browser is a part of a software other than the commercial web-browser

Comment: It's a pity, I ran into this one as well. Worked in Firefox but not in Chrome. Using 'postMessage' is the new way to talk to iframes, but you'll need code in both the sender and receiver pages.